# Moving between rooms via dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I already figured out the code to make this work. The only problem I have is how to use the dictionary rather then just doing a bunch of "if" statements with the comments needing to match my comments rather then the dictionary.

I was hoping for the same result as I implemented on my code, but with the use of actual comparison of keys or/and values for options of choice vice versa.

```
rooms = {
'Great Hall': {'South': 'Bedroom'},
'Bedroom': {'North': 'Great Hall', 'East': 'Cellar'},
'Cellar': {'West': 'Bedroom'}
}

location = 'Great Hall'  # Starting location for the player
# print('\n', *rooms[location].keys())

direction = ''  # assigning a value for user input ensuring it starts blank


def instructions():
    print("Welcome to the Milestone for Module 6.")
    print("Current instructions are as follows.")
    print("Type the right direction to go to the next room")
    print("When you move onto the game it will assist you with the right direction")
    print("You can type exit to leave the game after this menu")
    print("press Enter to start the game")


instructions()
input()


def main():
    if location == "Great Hall":
        print("Current Choice is South.")
    elif location == "Bedroom":
        print("Current Choice is North or East")
    elif location == "Cellar":
        print("Current Choice is West")


while direction != 'Exit':
    print("\nyou are currently held in", location)  # Stating the current position player is in

    choices = rooms[location].keys()
    print("Which direction would you like to choose?")
    main()
    direction = input()
    print("You entered", direction)

    if location == 'Great Hall':
        if direction == "South":
            location = 'Bedroom'
        elif direction == "Exit":
            print()
        else:
            print("Wrong Input")
    elif location == "Bedroom":
        if direction == "North":
            location = "Great Hall"
        elif direction == "East":
            location = "Cellar"
        elif direction == "Exit":
            print()
        else:
            print("Wrong input")
    elif location == "Cellar":
        if direction == "West":
            location = "Bedroom"
        elif direction == "Exit":
            print()
        else:
            print("Wrong input")
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I don't believe you have an actual question; I believe you already know how to solve this, and I would like to prove it to you. In your own words, when you wrote `choices = rooms[location].keys()`, *how does that work*? Why did you *not* write, for example, `if location == 'Great Hall': choices = {'South': 'Bedroom'}.keys()`, etc.? How did the dictionary help you avoid the need for `if` statements that time around? So, why not just... do that same thing again?

Comment: (Alternately: notice how you computed `choices` but then don't actually *do anything* with it? Why is that? Try to think back to when you wrote that line of code, and recall your thought process at the time. What did you want to do with the information?)

Comment: Hey Karl thanks for responding to my post! Yes , I noticed I did choices, and didn't necessarily involve the dictionary into the code. That is the problem I am having. I was trying to do it before, but then I was failing on bringing the terms from the dictionary to the if statements. For instance, I was wondering if there was a way to do something along the lines like (psuedocode below) 
`if location == .keys then`
`possible choices`

So thats what I mean by 'less' if statements using the dictionary. Also how to call it and compare it in if statements, because when I do it fails.

Answer (score 0):

Her is one way to replace the successive tests by a function:

```
rooms = {
'Great Hall': {'South': 'Bedroom'},
'Bedroom': {'North': 'Great Hall', 'East': 'Cellar'},
'Cellar': {'West': 'Bedroom'}
}

def possible_directions(room):
    print(f'Possible choices are: {" or ".join(rooms[room])}')

possible_directions('Bedroom')
```

Output:

```
Possible choices are: North or East
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I was wondering how would I be able to bring the dictionary values and keys to compare to user input. So (psueodocode) `if location == .key() then produce possible choices for new location`

Comment: Okay, so, notice the `rooms[room]` part in the code shown above? Do you understand what that does? What does it do?

Comment: Separately: when you created `rooms` in the first place, what was your own understanding of what it means, and how it would help you solve the overall problem? In your own words, what *is* a `dict`, and what is it good for?

Comment: From my understanding Karl, A dictionary is a sort of "database" where your allowed to store keys and values. My problem is being able to call those keys and values associated with their proper placement. So I was trying to shorten the if conditions because I know its possible by letting python access the dictionary and seeing if the proper keys are associated with proper values. Instead of writing all the keys in a bunch of if statements and not really using the dictionary at all.